# Работа с XML в Android [Java]

Tags: xml, java

**Добрый день!**

При работе с вот таким XML документом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <state>200</state>
  <error></error>
  <result>
    <user name="parent" title="NONE">
      <roles>
        <item>parent</item>
      </roles>
    </user>
  </result>
</response>
```

у меня возникли некоторые проблемы, связанные с его парсингом. Вот, как я вытягиваю из него информацию:

(для работы с XML я использую классы DocumentBuilderFactory->DocumentBuilder->Document)

```
... 
DocumentBuilderFactory dfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dbuilder= dfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
byte[] bytes = xmltext.getBytes();  // xmltext - текст XML
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Document xmldoc = dbuilder.parse(is);
xmldoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
...
NodeList d = xmldoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("roles");
String ut=d.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
...
```

В итоге получаю пустую строку в переменной "ut". А в ней должен быть текст "parent".

**Почему так происходит? Спасибо.**

Comment: Причем здесь Android? Удалил соответствующую метку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы форматирования (табы, пробелы, переводы строки) также являются "детьми" узла. В данном случае первым потомком узла `d` являются символ перевода строки и несколько пробелов отступа. Следующим потомком будет собственно элемент `item`. Чтобы избежать подобной ситуации можно при итерации по дереву проверять, реализует ли полученный элемент интерфейс `Element` - тогда это узел.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не знал о такой дурной штуке в XML. Интересно вот только, кому пришло в голову считать пробел потомком узла !? Ведь это бесполезно.

Comment: Авторам спецификации XML, вероятно. Кстати, если мне не изменяет память, то можно настроить парсер так, чтобы он пропускал все пробельные символы. Точно не помню, возможно это зависит от конкретной реализации парсера. В общем, Гугл вам в руки, дерзайте!